# Mobile android Chrome not displaying font-size correctly

Tags: android, google-chrome, font-size

When viewed on a Chrome Android Mobile, the font incorrectly sizes in a specific area of the webpage. If viewed in Desktop Mode on my Galaxy Note 8, the webpage font sizes correctly.

I have normalze.css, and a bit more:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

html {
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    -webkit-font-kerning: normal;
    font-kerning: normal;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    text-size-adjust: 100%;}
```

Any ideas?